# Problem on integral inequality

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

$$\ln 1 + \ln 2 + \cdots + \ln k ≥\int_1^k \log(x) \,\mathrm{d} x$$

I have no idea how to start as i have not seen this type of inequality before. I tried looking at the graphs and this is indeed true. However I have no idea how to prove this.
Any help would be aprreciated.

Comment: if we have $f(x) > 0$ and $f'(x) > 0,$  then
$$ \int_{a-1}^{b} \; f(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=a}^b \;  f(j) \; < \; \int_{a}^{b+1} \;  f(x) \; dx   $$  In your case drop the $\log 1$  which is zero anyway...Let's see, take $a = 2, b = k$

Comment: When you say, you tried looking at the graphs (plural), how were you graphing the sum on the left? If you're doing it sensibly, this should strongly suggest the inequality works, as well as lead to sensible strategies for a formal proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a closed interval $[a,b]$, with $a<b$, a partition of $[a,b]$ is a finite collection of points $D=\{x_i\}_{i=0}^n\subset[a,b]$ such that:
$$a=x_0\leq x_1\leq\ldots\leq x_{n-1}\leq x_n=b$$

If $f$ is a function bounded on $[a,b]$ then there exists $m,M$ such that $m\leq f(x)\leq M$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. So, for a bounded function and a partition $D=\{x_0,\ldots,x_n\}$ of $[a,b]$ we can define $$m_i:=\inf_{J_i}f,\quad M_i:=\sup_{J_i}f$$ where $J_i=(x_{i-1},x_i)$. At this point, the *inferior sum of $f$ relative to $D$* is defined by:
$$s(D,f):=\sum_{i=1}^nm_i\Delta x_i$$ with $\Delta x_i:=x_i-x_{i-1}$. Similarly the *superior sum of $f$ relative to $D$* is:
$$S(D,f):=\sum_{i=1}^nM_i\Delta x_i$$
Since $$m(b-1)\leq s(D,f)\leq S(D,f)\leq M(b-a)$$ we have that $$\inf_{D}S(D,f)\in\mathbb R,\quad \sup_{D}s(D,f)\in\mathbb R$$
With a little effort we should be able to prove that:
$$\sup_Ds(D,f)\leq \inf_DS(D,f)$$
This allows us to introduce the definition of Riemann-integrable function:

**Def:** A bounded function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is said to be Riemann-integrable on $[a,b]$ if $$\boxed{\sup_Ds(D,f)= \inf_DS(D,f)}$$
The Riemann integral of $f$ on $[a,b]$ is defined by:
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx:=\sup_Ds(D,f)= \inf_DS(D,f)$$

---

Turning back on your exercise $f(x)=\ln x$ is a bounded function on $[1,k]$ (since it is continuous on a compact set). Furthermore every continuous function is Riemann-integrable, so if you choose as a partition of $[0,k]$ the set $\tilde D=\{x_0=1,x_1=2,\ldots,x_{k-1}=k\}$, **by definition** you have that:
$$\int_1^k\ln xdx=\inf_DS(D,\ln x)\leq S(\tilde D,\ln x)$$
Since $\ln x$ is monotonically increasing on $[1,k]$, we conclude that $$M_i=\sup_{J_i}(\ln x)=\ln(x_i)$$ for every $i$. So, finally:
$$\int_1^k\ln(x)dx\leq S(\tilde D,\ln x)=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\ln(x_i)\underbrace{\Delta x_i}_{=1}=\ln 2+\ldots+\ln k$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\ln(x)$ is a monotonically increasing function, its definite integral is smaller then any corresponding upper sum. In particular, if we split up $[1,k]$ into intervals of length $1$ and take into account that $\ln(1)=0$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
    \int_1^k\ln(x)\,\mathrm{d}x &= \sum_{j=2}^k\int_{j-1}^j\ln(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
    &\leq \sum_{j=2}^k\sup_{x\in[j-1,j]}\ln(x)\\
    &= \sum_{j=2}^k\ln(j)\\
    &= \ln(1) + \ln(2) + \cdots + \ln(k).
\end{align*}